# C# DTO Layerd Architecture SQL Column missing

Tags: c#, dto

I used DTO to transfer the Data between layers, my BL is like below

```
public class BL_SizeRange
{
    public List<DTO_SizeRange> Get_SizeRange_Detail(DTO_SizeRange ObjDTO)
    {
        DL_SizeRange ObjDAL = new DL_SizeRange();
        return ObjDAL.Get_SizeRange_Detail(ObjDTO);
    }
}
```

I have relevant DTO as below

```
public class DTO_SizeRange : DTO_Common
{
        public string SIZE_RANGE_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public string SIZE_NAME { get; set; }
        public string INSEAM_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

My stored procedure return `SIZE_NAME` and `INSEAM_NAME` values only which defined in above DTO.

when I run I received an error called `SIZE_RANGE_DESCRIPTION` column does not belong to Table.

Comment: how `DL_SizeRange` looks like??

Comment: we need more detail, It's unclear